# Accidentally deleted the entire /usr folder

Tags: restore

Accidentally deleted the entire folder /usr. Can I restore it or repair?

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have a system backup ...

- Use the live CD to create a backup of your private documents and folders.
- Re-install **without** formatting.

This should leave everything user specific intact (including settings) and re-install all the missing files but it is always tricky hence the backup part.